# Which address should clients use for e-mail server to ensure SSL encryption?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, web

Currently we keep a DNS rule for every client that has mail.domain.com and this helps us redirect their mail to another server like GMail if they don't want to use our server. The problem is that when these domains change IPs or their individual SSL certs expire they can be locked out of their e-mail or have to confirm security exceptions they don't remove later.

To summarize we have something like this as DNS records:

```
domain.com         1.2.3.4
mail.domain.com    MX 1.2.3.4 <-- sometimes changes for people with GMail
```

The plan is we move our clients to using a single hostname for connecting to the mail server. So instead all clients would always connect to `mail.secureinternetthing.com` - This seems to work fine for new clients, as we tell them the new address to use, but for older clients we want to avoid clients having to change their settings.

If we change the MX record `mail.domain.com` to go to the same host as `mail.secureinternetthing.com` will our clients reject this?

Comment: What the what? Sorry, but I'm not following your question; I think you've got some DNS concepts mixed up. Clients don't use MX records at all, only mail servers do, specifically MTA (SMTP) servers. You can only ensure SSL or TLS connections between devices you control and others. You can't guarantee encryption outside that area of control. Perhaps if you take a step back and describe the policy or problem you're trying to implement/solve instead of the half-solution you've got going it would help to clarify your situation.

Comment: Sorry, when I said clients above I meant client DNS configuration on the server we host for them